# How to access Fragments and their associated UI elements from Main Activity

Tags: android

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get access to the Views associated with Fragments so I can manipulate the UI elements in each Fragment from the main activity.

This is my pertinent code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
    fManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fManager);
    this.setUpFragments();
    this.setUpUI();
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    //trying to access individual fragments and their views
}
```

Currently I'm trying to add more code to the end of this function to try and access the View elements but I can't seem to do it. Is this the correct place to do it or should I be attempting this somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't muck with fragments from their parents. Instead, write a method on the fragment that will perform the work you're trying to achieve. Think of a Fragment as a regular class, and the Fragment's Views as the class' private fields. Fragments allow and should be used for UX encapsulation.

Comment: So if I did have a method on the fragment to achieve the work, where would I tell the fragment to begin said method? In my fragment code I actually already included a method to try and set the text of a textfield in the fragment's layout however, I'm still having trouble getting it to work, which is why I was trying it the way I have shown above.

Comment: `Activity.onCreate()` is called long before `Fragment.onCreateView()` in the life cycle. If you must set the value in `onCreate`, you'll need to store that value as a field in the Fragment until `onCreateView` can build the View hierarchy and thus the TextField you're trying to control.