# Android Fragment TextView setText from main activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I got a MainActivity and it has 3 fragments. One of those fragments got one TextView. How Can I manipulate that TextView from MainActivity?

On my MainActivity I have a TabLayout with that 3 fragments. I got data from database in MainActivity and I would like to change the textview that is on fragment 1 with that data I got.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide some code or a little more detail on how/why you want the Activity to control the content of the TextView as opposed to, say the Fragment itself controlling it?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374241/how-to-access-fragments-and-their-associated-ui-elements-from-main-activity) answer from a similar question

Comment: I found something that worked: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25456/alterar-texto-do-textview-em-um-fragment-android
But is this a correct way to go?

Comment: Try to use LocalBroadCast

Answer (score 1):

I am suggest you to create some method in one of your Fragment
example :
In Fragment One create/ add this method :

```
public void Test(String jajal_disek) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), jajal_disek,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ABC.setText(jajal_disek); //example your textview name ABC
}
```

and then in MainActivity call that's method inside FragmentOne like this :

```
FragmentOne fragment = (FragmentOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_body);                
            fragment.Test("StackOverFlow");
```

Hope this will help you, be great if you write source code to identified problems